# Pytest hangs when a flask server runs another thread

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest, flask-testing

I am using Python3, Flask 0.12 and Pytest 3.0.7.

I have a flask app similar to this:

```
class AppInitializer:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def __function_to_be_refreshed():
        while True:
            try:
                time.sleep(5)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(e)


    def create_app(self):
        daemon_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__function_to_be_refreshed)
        daemon_thread.daemon = True
        daemon_thread.start()
        atexit.register(daemon_thread.join)
        app_ = Flask(__name__)
        return app_


app_initializer = AppInitializer()
app = app_initializer.create_app()
```

I am trying to test this app using pytest as follows:

```
import unittest

import pytest


class TestCheckPriceRequestAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = api.app.test_client()

    def test_random(self):
        pass
```

When I run this test using `pytest`, this test (along with all other tests) runs successfully but pytest hangs. How to stop the running pytest process (or maybe kill the daemon thread)?

Comment: Well a flask app has no business spawning threads

Comment: @e4c5: It was an added requirement in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `join` command only means that threading will wait until thread finishes, but wouldn't finish it. To end thread with endless loop you could do like this:

```
class AppInitializer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._run = True
        self._daemon_thread = None

    def __function_to_be_refreshed(self):
        while self._run:
            try:
                time.sleep(5)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(e)

    def __shutdown(self):
        self._run = False
        if self._daemon_thread:
            self._daemon_thread.join()

    def create_app(self):
        self._daemon_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__function_to_be_refreshed)
        ...
        atexit.register(self.__shutdown)
        ...
```

Comment: I got confused between finishing a thread and it's termination. Thanks for the suggestion :)